# How to find Max and mean values from file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a sample file like

```
stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7

stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7

stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7
```

What I have to do is to find max and mean value for each stat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  What have you tried?  How do you calculate a min value, a max value, the mean value?  Are any of the numbers ever negative?  Is it all values in column 3, or do you need to group by column 1, for example?

Comment: Hi I have tried comparing values of $3 in awk for finding max which i am able to find for 1 stat but how can i generalized it if there are more stat.Yes the values are non-negative and they always will be in column 3.

Comment: Do You want to have mean and max for stat<n> or for the different series or for all the numbers?

Comment: Well, given the example input, it's pretty trivial to say that the max and mean for stat1 and stat2 are all 0, while the max and mean for stat3 is 349.7... I assume your real files will actually show some variance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{
         if (NF != 3) next
         sum[$1] += $3;
         if (cnt[$1]++ == 0) { max[$1] = $3; min[$1] = $3; }
         if ($3 > max[$1]) max[$1] = $3
         if ($3 < min[$1]) min[$1] = $3
     }
     END {
         printf "%-8s %4s %8s %8s %8s\n", "Sample", "N", "Minimum", "Maximum", "Average"
         for (key in sum)
         {
             printf "%-8s %4d %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f\n", key, cnt[key], min[key], max[key], sum[key]/cnt[key]
         }
     }' data-file
```

Sample output (from the data in the question, which is singularly unexciting):

```
Sample      N  Minimum  Maximum  Average
stat2:      3     0.00     0.00     0.00
stat1:      3     0.00     0.00     0.00
stat3:      3   349.70   349.70   349.70
```

This code includes the minimum as well as the maximum; it's easy to remove if it is unwanted.  Note that it skips blank lines in the data file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Perl:

```
perl -lane '{ if(/(stat\d+)/) {
    $m{$1} =$F[2] if $m{$1}<$F[2] || !$m{$_};
    $s{$1}+=$F[2]; $c{$1}++
}} END{print "$_: $m{$_},".$s{$_}/$c{$_} for keys %c}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward using awk associative arrays:

*meanmax.awk*

```awk
# Skip empty lines
NF==0 { next }

# Keep a tally of number of elements and their sum
{ cnt[$1]++; sum[$1] += $3 }

# If max[$1] has not been defined or if it is smaller than $3
cnt[$1] == 1 || max[$1] < $3 {
  max[$1] = $3
}

END {
  for (k in sum)
    print k, max[k], sum[k]/cnt[k]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f meanmax.awk infile
```

Output:

```
stat1: 0.0 0                    
stat2: 0.0 0
stat3: 349.7 349.7
```

Or if run on the originally posted input:

```
stat1: 18.0 10.3333             
stat2: 45.0 16.6667
stat3: 239.7 89.4667
```

Comment: You probably use Perl.  What Perl calls a _hash_, `awk` calls an _associative array_.  I use both langugages, but they're definitely [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays) in `awk`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I always think of them as hashes because that's how they are indexed, but you're right the more correct term is associative array. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If You need the mean and max of all values, You can try something like this

```
awk '/sample:/ {s[$1] += $3; if(++n[$1]==1 || max[$1]<$3) max[$1] = $3}
END { for (i in s) print i" mean = "s[i]/n[i]", max = "max[i] }
' <<EOT
stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7

stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7

stat1:  sample:        0.0
stat2:  sample:        0.0
stat3:  sample:        349.7
EOT
```

Output:

```
stat3: mean = 349.7, max = 349.7
stat1: mean = 0, max = 0.0
stat2: mean = 0, max = 0.0
```